# JSON_VALUE Msg 13609, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'p' is found at position 0

Tags: sql-server

When I ran the following query on our SQL Server, the query ran fine and returned the correct result.

```
select 
    LEFV.TextValue,
    json_value (LEFV.TextValue, '$."st4TempSensorValue.1.1"') as TempValue
from 
    SolarWindsOrionLog.dbo.OrionLog_LogEntryFieldValue LEFV
where
    LEFV.TextValue like  '%st4TempSensorValue%'
```

But as soon as I join with another table, I get an error

> Msg 13609, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'p' is found at position 0

```
select 
    LEFV.TextValue,
    json_value (LEFV.TextValue, '$."st4TempSensorValue.1.1"') TempValue,
    LE.LogEntryMessageSourceID
from
    SolarWindsOrionLog.dbo.OrionLog_LogEntryFieldValue LEFV
inner join 
    SolarWindsOrionLog.dbo.OrionLog_LogEntry LE on LEFV.LogEntryID = LE.LogEntryID and LEFV.PartitionID = LE.PartitionID
where
    LEFV.TextValue like '%st4TempSensorValue%'
```

The datatype of `[TextValue]` is `[nvarchar](max)`.

Could anyone please help me debug this query? Thank you for you help!

Comment: Can you provide a replication? What you say *shouldn't* happen unless there's something we're missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the field is JSON before trying to search inside it. Something like this

```
select LEFV.TextValue
   ,CASE WHEN ISJSON(LEFV.TextValue)>0 THEN json_value(LEFV.TextValue,'$."st4TempSensorValue.1.1"') ELSE NULL END AS TempValue
   ,LE.LogEntryMessageSourceID
from SolarWindsOrionLog.dbo.OrionLog_LogEntryFieldValue LEFV
inner join SolarWindsOrionLog.dbo.OrionLog_LogEntry LE
ON LEFV.LogEntryID = LE.LogEntryID AND LEFV.PartitionID = LE.PartitionID
WHERE ISJSON(LEFV.TextValue)>0 AND LEFV.TextValue like '%st4TempSensorValue%'
```

It's probably trying to parse an invalid value to Json.